# Serializer for class is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly

Tags: android, kotlinx.serialization, android-jetpack-datastore

Released APK crashes with next error:

```
Serializer for class 'User' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.

@Keep
@Serializable
data class User(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String? = null,
    val token: String? = null
)

@ExperimentalSerializationApi
object UserSerializer : Serializer<User> {
    override val defaultValue: User
        get() = User()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): User {
        return ProtoBuf.decodeFromByteArray(input.readBytes())
    }

    override suspend fun writeTo(t: User, output: OutputStream) {
        output.write(ProtoBuf.encodeToByteArray(t))
    }
}
```

I added official proguard rules from

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android

(with my package of course)

Even added `@Keep` to `User` class but still it crashes

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Found the issue. I actually had one companion object inside `User` and had to add @Keep for this one as well to fix the issue:

```
@Keep
@Serializable
data class User(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String? = null,
    val token: String? = null,
    ...
) {
    @Keep
    companion object {
        const val ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: From the link you provided they say: "You may also want to keep all custom serializers you've defined."

Comment: @Vadik do you mean keep `UserSerializer` as well? Already tried it, didn't help

Comment: @Vadik I updated the question, it seems fixed now